# How to edit inline page fields?

Tags: visualforce, inline, include

I have a page where I have included an inline page. This inline page has fields which are editable. If I test this page alone fields are editable. But when I test the main page which has inline page, the fields are not editable. How can I make them editable?.

I tried to use  but is displaying the content from standard layout also . So there is a duplication of content but the fields are editable. How can i avoid the duplicate content?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Powerfailure" columns="1" >
<apex:include pageName="Powerf1"/>
<apex:detail inlineedit="True" Relatedfields = "False"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Are your `Page` and `inline Page` both Visualforce pages?

Comment: @Mahmood, Yes. Both are Visual force pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature for Inline editing is not available in sales force with related list.

There is an idea posted on SF Community portal.Do up vote it if you feel so.

[Inline Editing for Related Lists](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpXFAA0)

There are a couple AppExchange apps that may offer what you're looking for --

[Mass Update And Mass Edit From List View](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ)

[Mass Edit + Mass Update + Mass Delete](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003J6KcEAK)

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong. So since inline page is related list we cannot use inline editing for inline page.

Comment: As soon as the page is added as related list, inline edit functionality stops working when accessed from the related list.If you directly test the page,inline should work for you

Comment: Thanks Samir, Is there any workaround for this other than usign AppExchange apps? Can I bring the whole code of inline page to main page and make it work. Not that I will do it. But just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: As mentioned earlier Inline edit work in the main page.It just wont work in related list.There is an idea for this as well.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you share that idea?

Comment: Idea means which is yet to be implemented.I shared the link for the same in the answer

Comment: Iam not sure if I can ask here as its may be related to inlineedit. I have two tabs on inline page. when i click on second tab in inline page, it does not work. It also has editable fields. Is it because of inlineedit issue?

Comment: Not sure.Create a new question and post the code there

Comment: inlineEdit for inline page is working now

Comment: how did you achieve that?

Comment: Samir,    I set the flag disabled = 'false'. It worked.